# How to configure tftp server on Fedora 23?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I have installed the tftp server using:

*#dnf install tftp-server*

How do i set the tftp server directory ? I don't see any tftp related config files in /etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora 17 onwards uses systemd for controlling the tftp service.  The applicable systemd configuration:

/lib/systemd/system/tftp.service

Quoting from my Fedora 27 installation, you want to tweak the parameter after `-s`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tftp Server
Requires=tftp.socket
Documentation=man:in.tftpd

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
StandardInput=socket

[Install]
Also=tftp.socket
```

The man page is a good reference of in.tftpd for additional options.

On a side note SeLinux rules expect TFTP to be served out of the above folder, so you'll probably need to reconfigure those (or *cough* switch off SeLinux).

Answer (score -1):

you should look at the systemd service file:

/var/lib/tftpboot

http://dflund.se/~triad/krad/tftpserver.html